# reflow text in PDF documents (iPhone, CGPDFDocumentRef)

Tags: iphone, pdf, cgpdfdocument

I'm using [CGPDFDocumentRef](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html) to render PDF content for an ebook app.  This works great, but it seems to preclude allowing the user to read text in "landscape mode" by tilting the phone- I have no way to reflow the text to make use of the wider space.  (Yes, I can scale the whole page to fit the new space, but that's not really helpful to the reader.)

**Is it possible to reflow paragraph text in PDF documents based on a given page width?**  I realize that HTML does this nicely, but the "export to HTML" from tools such as Keynote just draws a JPG.

If what I'm asking for is impossible, that would be an acceptable answer; I'd just like to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is technically possible to temporarily reflow text in PDFs to the full width of the page, but I haven't been able to find any functionality in CGPDFDocumentRef reference that would enable you to take advantage of this PDF feature.

On a somewhat related note, if you do manage to find the necessary functionality, creating a tagged PDF makes automatic reflow of text and associated graphics easier and more accurate.

However, I don't believe that CGPDFDocumentRef lets you create tagged PDFs either.

Comment: Cool, I really thought it wasn't possible.  I think I will base my ebook reader app on PDF, and implement landscape viewing in a future update if the reflowing solution ever surfaces. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. The PDF reference can be found online using the link below. You might find it useful while building your apps, just to get some background info when necessary.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html